# Oracle Rest Data Service return a collection as JSON

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle-ords

I have some data in a collection, and I would like to send it as a result set in the response body.

Is it possible parse an associative array to JSON, and then send it as a result set?

Comment: do you mean Oracle Rest Data Services ( ORDS ) ??

Comment: Yes, sorry.......

Comment: where is the collection stored ? you can stored a collection in a type and return  it as sys_refcursor , then you can build a ords service to collect it as json using apex_json

Comment: The collection is local in a function. I know that I can create a schema level type (both collection and record) and then select from it, but I would like to solve it locally within a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RobertoHernandez gave a basic overview of the ORDS service which is not exactly what I was searching for, but thanks!

1. The function which fills the collection and creates the JSON object:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get_data RETURN CLOB
AS
    cst_key CONSTANT VARCHAR(32) := 'KEY';
    cst_value CONSTANT VARCHAR(32) := 'VALUE';

    TYPE r_summary IS RECORD (
        key   VARCHAR2(255),
        value NUMBER
    ); 
    
    TYPE t_summary IS TABLE OF r_summary INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    
    r_s     r_summary;
    tab_s t_summary;

    json_clob CLOB;
 
    i INTEGER;   
BEGIN
    -- insert some dummy data to the collection
    FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
        r_s.key := dbms_random.string('A', 10);
        r_s.value := ROUND(dbms_random.value(1,10), 2);
        
        tab_s(tab_s.COUNT + 1) := r_s;
    END LOOP;
    
    -- write data to a JSON object
    APEX_JSON.initialize_clob_output;
    APEX_JSON.open_object;
    
    APEX_JSON.open_array('data');
   
    IF tab_s.COUNT > 0 THEN
        FOR i IN tab_s.FIRST..tab_s.LAST LOOP
            IF tab_s.EXISTS(i) THEN
                APEX_JSON.open_object;
                APEX_JSON.write(cst_key, tab_s(i).key);
                APEX_JSON.write(cst_value, tab_s(i).value);
                APEX_JSON.close_object;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
    
    APEX_JSON.close_all;
    
    json_clob := APEX_JSON.get_clob_output;
    APEX_JSON.free_output;
   
    RETURN json_clob;
END;
```

2. Create the web service as:

```
BEGIN
  ORDS.DEFINE_MODULE(
      p_module_name    => 'test',
      p_base_path      => '/data/',
      p_items_per_page =>  25,
      p_status         => 'PUBLISHED',
      p_comments       => NULL);  
  
  ORDS.DEFINE_TEMPLATE(
      p_module_name    => 'test',
      p_pattern        => 'all',
      p_priority       => 0,
      p_etag_type      => 'HASH',
      p_etag_query     => NULL,
      p_comments       => NULL);
  ORDS.DEFINE_HANDLER(
      p_module_name    => 'test',
      p_pattern        => 'all',
      p_method         => 'GET',
      p_source_type    => 'resource/lob',
      p_items_per_page =>  25,
      p_mimes_allowed  => '',
      p_comments       => NULL,
      p_source         => 
'SELECT
    ''application/json'',
    f_get_data
FROM
    sys.dual'
      );


  COMMIT; 
END;
```

3. Finally call the ORDS:

```
http://<host>:<port>/ords/<db>/<schema>/data/all/
```

For more details read the following article which gave me the idea (credis to @thatjeffsmith ):

https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/09/ords-returning-raw-json/

Answer (score 2):

As requested, let me show you how to use a collection embedded in a type to create a json and deliver it by a web rest service

Let's imagine I have the data of my employees in a table and I want to retrieve them by a web service using JSON. In this case I use ORDS, APEX 5.1.4 and Oracle 12c

1.This procedure retrieves the information in JSON using APEX_JSON. I think APEX_JSON is quite good for JSON generation in Oracle 12c, because there is a lot of bugs related with JSON in 12c.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_emp_json (p_empno IN emp.empno%TYPE DEFAULT NULL) AS
  l_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  
  OPEN l_cursor FOR
    SELECT e.empno AS "empno",
           e.ename AS "employee_name",
           e.job AS "job",
           e.mgr AS "mgr",
           TO_CHAR(e.hiredate,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "hiredate",
           e.sal AS "sal",
           e.comm  AS "comm",
           e.deptno AS "deptno"
    FROM   emp e
    WHERE  e.empno = DECODE(p_empno, NULL, e.empno, p_empno);

  APEX_JSON.open_object;
  APEX_JSON.write('employees', l_cursor);
  APEX_JSON.close_object;
END;
/
```

2.Build the ORDS REST module ( in your own schema )

```
BEGIN
  ORDS.define_module(
    p_module_name    => 'rest-v4',
    p_base_path      => 'rest-v4/',
    p_items_per_page => 0);
  
  ORDS.define_template(
   p_module_name    => 'rest-v4',
   p_pattern        => 'employees/');

  ORDS.define_handler(
    p_module_name    => 'rest-v4',
    p_pattern        => 'employees/',
    p_method         => 'GET',
    p_source_type    => ORDS.source_type_plsql,
    p_source         => 'BEGIN get_emp_json; END;',
    p_items_per_page => 0);
    
  ORDS.define_template(
   p_module_name    => 'rest-v4',
   p_pattern        => 'employees/:empno');

  ORDS.define_handler(
    p_module_name    => 'rest-v4',
    p_pattern        => 'employees/:empno',
    p_method         => 'GET',
    p_source_type    => ORDS.source_type_plsql,
    p_source         => 'BEGIN get_emp_json(:empno); END;',
    p_items_per_page => 0);
    
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

3.Call the REST WEB SERVICE

```
http://yourhost:yourport/ords/hr/rest-v4/employees/
```

**Conclusion**

ORDS is a great tool to create web services using REST to retrieve in JSON format data from your database. Adapt it to your own needs. Normally the collection can be derived from a table or a type. In my example I use a SYS_REFCURSOR object to retrieve the JSON data.

The following articles possess great examples and guides step-by-step

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-create-basic-rest-web-services-using-plsql#create-get-web-services

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-restful-web-services-handling-complex-json-payloads

Answer (score 0):

This technique, returning a `refcursor` will also work for an `autorest` situation when you want to return an JSON array as an out parameter.

You will have to declare the record and the type at the schema or package level to get it to work.

```
FUNCTION f_get_data
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
    cst_key     CONSTANT VARCHAR(32) := 'KEY';
    cst_value   CONSTANT VARCHAR(32) := 'VALUE';


    r_s                  r_summary;
    tab_s                t_summary;

    json_clob            SYS_REFCURSOR;

    i                    INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- insert some dummy data to the collection
    FOR i IN 1 .. 10
    LOOP
        r_s.key := DBMS_RANDOM.string('A', 10);
        r_s.VALUE := ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 10), 2);

        tab_s(tab_s.COUNT + 1) := r_s;
    END LOOP;

    OPEN json_clob FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(tab_s);

    RETURN json_clob;
END;
```